# Laravel Translation Still `en` even if locale changed

Tags: laravel, laravel-localization, laravel-translatable

i'm trying to change language with laravel but it still en (fallback_locale)

locale changes successfully to another language but laravel still depends on fallback_locale

while changing fallback locale to 'ar' as example, blade  prints the key as `web.product.name`

i tried `trans('web.product.name',[],'ar');` in tinker cmd and it works fine

/config/app.php

```
'locale' => 'ar',
'locales' => ['en', 'ar', 'ku', 'tu'],
```

`php artisan cache:clear` does not effect

echo 'locale' anywhere returns what i set but lang still en

Comment: Do you have translation files in your folder `resources/lang/ar/...`?

Comment: yes it is `resources/lang/ar/web.php ` ` resources/lang/en/web.php `

Comment: as i mentioned tinker works fine so that mean path is correct

Comment: can I see your resources/lang/ar/web.php file.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried clearing your cache?

```
php artisan config:clear
```